# Display a "There is no item matching your search" message in a search filter made with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning Javascript by doing exercises, this time I decided to create my own search filter which works correctly but I would like to add a message for when the results don't match the items. I have searched yotube for the search filter but they don't put the message mentioned above. Thanks for reading me.

Html

```
<section id="seccion-diez" class="section">
            <h2 data-dark>Filtro de Búsqueda</h2>
            <input type="search" name="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar..." class="card-filter">
            <p class="hidden" id="mensaje">Los resultados no coincinden con la busqueda</p>
            <article class="contenedor-cards">
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" alt="nature">
                    <figcaption>Naturaleza</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" alt="any">
                    <figcaption>Random</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech" alt="tech">
                    <figcaption>Tecnología</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="people">
                    <figcaption>Persona</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" alt="animals">
                    <figcaption>Animal</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <figure class="card">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch" alt="arch">
                    <figcaption>Arquitectura</figcaption>
                </figure>
                
            </article>

    </section>
```

I'm working with imports, here's my code for them

```
<script type="module" src="./js/index.js" ></script>
```

Index.js (imports)

```
import filtroBusqueda from './filtro_de_busqueda.js';
const d=document;
d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
filtroBusqueda('.card-filter', '.card');
```

});

Mi filtro de busqueda.js

```
const d=document;

export default function filtroBusqueda(input, selector){
d.addEventListener('keyup', e =>{
    if (e.target.matches(input)) {
        // console.log(e.target.value)

        if (e.key==='Escape') e.target.value=''; 
        
        d.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elemento =>
            elemento.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value) 
                ? elemento.classList.remove("filter")              
                : elemento.classList.add("filter")


            );
        }
    })

}
```

CSS

```
.filter{
 visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  order: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage the display of the message by `result.length`.

- I replaced the name of the class `filter` with `hidden` to be clearer and avoid duplication.
- `visibility: hidden` does not show content but still affects layout. So `display: none` would be more suitable for your code. (cf. [MDN - visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility))

  > To both hide an element and remove it from the document layout, set the display property to none instead of using visibility.
- Early return statement is helpful to reduce the depths. 
  ex) `if (!e.target.matches(input)) return;`

### Solution

```js
const d = document;

function filtroBusqueda(input, selector) {
  d.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (!e.target.matches(input)) return;
    if (e.key === "Escape") e.target.value = "";

    d.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((elemento) => {
      elemento.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value)
        ? elemento.classList.remove("hidden")
        : elemento.classList.add("hidden");
    });

    const result = [...d.querySelectorAll(".card")].filter(
      (elemento) => !elemento.classList.contains("hidden")
    );
    result.length
      ? d.querySelector("#mensaje").classList.add("hidden")
      : d.querySelector("#mensaje").classList.remove("hidden");
  });
}

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  filtroBusqueda(".card-filter", ".card");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="seccion-diez" class="section">
  <h2 data-dark>Filtro de Búsqueda</h2>
  <input type="search" name="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar..." class="card-filter">
  <p class="hidden" id="mensaje">Los resultados no coincinden con la busqueda</p>
  <article class="contenedor-cards">
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" alt="nature">
      <figcaption>Naturaleza</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" alt="any">
      <figcaption>Random</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech" alt="tech">
      <figcaption>Tecnología</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="people">
      <figcaption>Persona</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" alt="animals">
      <figcaption>Animal</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="card">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch" alt="arch">
      <figcaption>Arquitectura</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: you are awesome!!!! thank you so much for the help. I hope to have that logic to solve these problems in the future.